# Is it possible to display an .xls file in an <object> html tag?

Tags: html, excel, tags

For a CMS-like web app we are writing, we need to show a preview of an Excel file.

We try with the `<object>` tag, setting the data attribute like this:

```
data = "myFile.xls"
```

but we didn't succeed. The page, in IE and Chrome, alert that we don't have the necessary plugin, even if we have Office installed.

Does anyone have any experience in such a task?

Comment: Thank you for the code-editing on question.